# Javascript: Group data by dates and fill in the days in between

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have a event data array of objects with just the end and start date for each event.

```
let listOfEvents = [{
  "end": Date 2017-12-09T11:12:00.000Z,
  "start": Date 2017-12-14T03:12:00.000Z,
  "title": "Event One"
},{
  "end": Date 2017-11-10T11:12:00.000Z,
  "start": Date 2017-11-12T03:12:00.000Z,
  "title": "Event Two"
}]
```

This is what I want the final output to be

```
    let listOfEvents = [{
      "date": Date 2017-12-09T11:12:00.000Z,
      "title": "Event One"
    },{
      "date": Date 2017-12-10T11:12:00.000Z,
      "title": "Event One"
    }{
      "date": Date 2017-12-11T11:12:00.000Z,
      "title": "Event One"
    }{
      "date": Date 2017-12-12T11:12:00.000Z,
      "title": "Event One"
    }{
      "date": Date 2017-12-13T03:12:00.000Z,
      "title": "Event One"
    }{
      "date": Date 2017-12-14T11:12:00.000Z,
      "title": "Event One"
    },{
      "date": Date 2017-11-10T11:12:00.000Z,
      "title": "Event Two"
    },{
      "date": Date 2017-11-11T03:12:00.000Z,
      "title": "Event Two"
    },{
      "date": Date 2017-11-12T03:12:00.000Z,
      "title": "Event Two"
    }]
```

This is what I have currently,

```
let newEvents = [];    
listOfEvents.forEach(function (item) {
        newEvents.push({
            date: item.start,
            title: item.title
        })
    });
```

How would I add logic to fill in the day and add a day for each new entry to the end date then continue on the loop? I can include momentjs if needed.

Comment: The expected output is confusing. Do you care about the time as well? Or did you randomly set the time component in the entries? i.e: 03:12 & 11:12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` and compare the dates and keep adding each new day to result array till your end date is less than start date.

```js
let listOfEvents = [{ "end": "2017-12-09T11:12:00.000Z", "start": "2017-12-14T03:12:00.000Z", "title": "Event One" },{ "end": "2017-11-10T11:12:00.000Z", "start": "2017-11-12T03:12:00.000Z", "title": "Event Two" }];

var result = listOfEvents.reduce((r, {
  end,
  start,
  title
}) => {
  end = new Date(end);
  start = new Date(start);

  while (end < start) {
    r.push({
      'date': new Date(end),
      title
    });
    end.setDate(end.getDate() + 1);
  }
  if (Math.abs(start.getTime() - end.getTime()) < 1000 * 3600 * 24) {
    r.push({
      'date': new Date(start),
      title
    });
  }

  return r;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. I am just trying to understand what is the need for the if statement inside the reduce function?

Comment: The if conditions adds the `start` date if the difference between end data and start date is less than a day.

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense but I am getting an error saying getTime() is not a function. Am I missing something else?

Comment: The snippet is working in Chrome and Firefox. [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) is a function. Try logging at console and see for any error.

Comment: User error hence why i was getting that error. I was trying to use moment with that function and it doesn't have that. But it is all good thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the function that creates a range based on a given input, and then reduce the events into a new array

Note that with the data given, `start` and `end` properties seem to have been inverted, and the given question doesn't say if it should purely compare on date or on datetime. Where [@Hassans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47726225/3231537) adds an item to the dataset when ready, I specifically ignored this as I believe this is up to specification

```js
const extractDateRange = ( range, transform ) => {
  let results = [];
  // note that start and end date seem to be up side down in the question
  let curDate = new Date(range.end);
  let endDate = new Date(range.start);
  while (curDate <= endDate) {
    results.push( transform( new Date(curDate), range ) );
    curDate.setDate( curDate.getDate() + 1 ); // / add 1 day
  }
  return results;
};

let listOfEvents = [{
  "end": '2017-12-09T11:12:00.000Z',
  "start": '2017-12-14T03:12:00.000Z',
  "title": "Event One"
},{
  "end": '2017-11-10T11:12:00.000Z',
  "start": '2017-11-12T03:12:00.000Z',
  "title": "Event Two"
}];

let allEvents = listOfEvents.reduce( (current, item) => current.concat( 
  extractDateRange( item, ( date, props ) => ({ 
    title: props.title, 
    date 
  }) ) )
, []);

console.log( allEvents );
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and interesting take on this. Just wondering why when I console the log I get the data like [0...99][100...121] ? Like it is splitting the data into two groups as oppose to one big array.

Comment: @Kevin Yeah, no worries, that's the standard output in the console, simply to make it more human readable :)